# Property forwarding to child properties

Tags: c#, .net-5

I have a many objects of the same type (the base type is DisplayTool) in a list. The type is not determined at compile time but could be any type that has been added via a plugin system.

Let's assume I have a property called IsActive I currently need to go through all properties in the list an set the value. Additionally a single value of one object can be set.

Currently I need to do this for every property but I don't know them in advance so I was thinking of some WrapperObject that bundles the attached objects in a list and builds the properties dynamically. The ExpandoObject would be useful in this case but it doesn't bundle the properties into one.

The WinForms Property Inspector is a good example for the behavior I want. If the properties of a property of a all attached objects are the same, the value is shown, if not all values are the same it is not shown.

I have created my own MockObject derived from ExpandoObject that collects the properties and displays them. I only wanted to ask if there is already an implementation from the framework that does the same?

Comment: If the number of properties is not too high (like, dozens), I would instead define some Interfaces, like `IActivable` which exposes the property `IsActive { get; set; }`. This way you can cast and match the type and do everything type-safe. I call this "the sane way"

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues. That would be an option but my problem is that I only know the basic interface with a few properties (~5). The rest comes from different implementations where the core app does know nothing about. I have also edited my question what I already have.

Comment: What kind of operations are you planning to do on those objects that you don't know which properties they have?

Comment: To keep it short. We have a basic framework that can do image manipulation. Each user can create its own interaction module with individual properties that are not delivered by the framework itself. For example one module can only create lines, but another module can create specific image segmentation. Each of them has seperate (maybe not overlapping) properties. There are different displays with individual interaction modules . If for example I want to switch a property (e.g. Radius) I want to merge this operation into one so that I do not have to go through each display.